Translateable React label components issue
I have created a MessageLabel component, which is used as follows:
<button><MessageLabel>signin</MessageLabel></button>

The MessageLabel component uses the placeholder label as a key to find the actual label value in the object that is being fetched by the Translator component. Currently the language is not configurable by the user, but is included in the API request for future proofing.
import Translator from "./translation_provider";

const MessageLabel = (msgKey) => {
    const key = msgKey.children;
    const getMessageKey = () => {
        if (Translator.messages){
            return Translator.messages[key]
        } else {
            return key
        }
    }

    return (
        getMessageKey()
    );
};
  
export default MessageLabel;

The Translator component:
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "../api/axios"
import config from '../config/config';

const FetchTranslations = async (lang) => {
    const langURL = config.TRANSLATIONS_URL + "/" + lang;
    const [waitingForResponse, setWaitingForResponse] = useState(false);
   
    setWaitingForResponse(true);
        
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(
            langURL,
            config.HEADERS
        );
        
        if (response.data){
            for (var id in response.data.language) {
                Messages[response.data.language[id].msgKey] = response.data.language[id].message;
            }
    
         Translator.setMessages(Messages);

            return Messages
        }
    } catch(err) {
        // TODO - catch errors
    }
}

const Translator = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState({});

    function isEmpty(obj) {
        for (const prop in obj) {
          if (Object.hasOwn(obj, prop)) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
    }

    if (isEmpty(messages)){  // used to be messages == {} when the question was first published
        setMessages(FetchTranslations('bg')); // TODO - make language configurable by user
    }
}

export default Translator;


The Translator component sends a GET request to the API endpoint set up in the config file. The API request does return the correct data in the correct format.
What I'm expecting to see is the label with the placeholder text until the translations are received and then to have them replaced with the actual texts. However they are not getting replaced and I can't figure out why. I suspect I'm not using the hooks correctly.
Edit:
After @DBS suggestion I reworked the check for an empty object and added the isEmpty() function. The issue I'm having now is that every instance of MessageLabel is calling the API and as a result I'm getting a "Too many re-renders" error

Objects with the same contents aren't equal in JS, messages == {} will never be true as those are two separate object references. You could use a useEffect with an empty dependency array to run your code on initial load.

2 issues I see here: You're trying to use Translator.setMessages as if it was an object's member when it's a local function variable, and you're trying to use setMessages with FetchTranslations which returns a Promise. None of those approaches will work. Your best bet is to use a Context to hold the translations and useEffect to fetch them and set them at the context's state.

The approach you were sharing is flawed for many reasons:

You're trying to access a function's local variables from outside as if they were member properties.
You're trying to setting a Promise into a state which doesn't really help you.
You're trying to use a components state "globally". State is dependent on the component instance. Two of the same component will have independent state.

Overall I'd recommend you check out some more on React and JavaScript in general.

As for your issue, you should use a Context to have shared state in your application. A context provider will work as a "state holder" that will be shared in your application, so anybody can use it from anywhere in the component tree (so long as they're descendants of the provider).
Your fetching logic should be done inside a useEffect because it is an asynchronous operation.

How about something like this?

Create a TranslatorContext.jsx file with something along the lines of:

import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "../api/axios"
import config from '../config/config';

const TranslatorContext = createContext({});

export const TranslatorContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMessages = async () => {        
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
            langURL,
            config.HEADERS
        );
        
        if (response.data){
            const messages = {}
            for (var id in response.data.language) {
                messages[response.data.language[id].msgKey] = response.data.language[id].message;
            }
    
            setMessages(messages);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        // TODO - catch errors
    }
    };

    fetchMessages();
  }, []);

  const translate = (key) => {
    if (typeof messages[key] === "undefined") {
      return key;
    }

    return messages[key];
  };

  const context = {
    messages,
    t: translate,
  };
  return (
    <TranslatorContext.Provider value={context}>
      {children}
    </TranslatorContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTranslator = () => {
  return useContext(TranslatorContext);
};

This exports the TranslatorContextProvider component that should wrap your entire application and a hook to use this provider directly. The hook would return whatever is inside the context variable provided inside, which in this case is the messages object and a t function used to get the proper message with custom logic.

Wrap your app with TranslatorContextProvider.

In the main component (typically named App but it varies from person to person), you should wrap your entire application with this context provider:
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <TranslatorContextProvider>
      <RestOfMyApp />
    </TranslatorContextProvider>
  );
);


Use the hook from the components that need translating.

For example,
const MyButton = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslator();

  return (
    <button>
      {t('signin')}
    </button>
  );
}

This will render a button that says signin until the real message key is fetched which will then automatically replace it with the correct text.

If you need a more detailed example, check out this CodeSandbox:

